# Is there a "nice" description of the algebraic closure of the field of multivariable polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm interested in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ (multivariable polynomials with integer coefficients).  Specifically, I want to know its algebraic closure (the set of roots of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n][y]$ - that is, polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$).

I am wondering if there is some "nice" characterization of this set.  A good answer might be something like "the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is the set of polynomials in $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with coefficients algebraic in $\mathbb{Z}$."  But I just made that up, and it's probably not true.  Is there some characterization along these lines?

Comment: With one variable I suspect it's the field of [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) over $\bf Q$. Not sure about the situation with multiple variables though.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, ... x_n]$ isn't a field. Note also that the algebraic closure of its fraction field contains, e.g. $\sqrt{x_i}$. I don't think there's a nice description of the algebraic closure.

Comment: @anon: the field of Puiseux series is too big.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking Laurent series as the base field. The algebraic closure here will necessarily be countable.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu - edited "field" to "ring."

Comment: Of course at the very least it contains the field of all algebraic numbers.

Comment: Dear LevDub, First of all, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ as you define it (this is *not* standard terminology, since $\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is not a field) is the same as the algebraic closure of its fraction field $\mathbb Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.  Secondly, it certainly doesn't have any easy description of the kind you suggest, even if $n = 1$.  Regards,